# how to change the action link button style in chhtml

Tags: html, css, razor, styles, stylesheet

i need to display the all button in same style. all button i but the div content and using class name i figured nicely. but only one button i need to put the html.actionlink type. but this button only text size and text family entirely difference from others. my code is below. how to solve this? . thank you for your advance guide

```
 <div id="exportButton">
            @Html.ActionLink("Export", "Export", new { page = 1, pageSize = 0, orderBy = "~", filter = "~"}, new { id = "exportSearchLink", @class = "button w100 " })
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Please Edit Me", "Edit", null, new { style="font-weight:bold;" })
```